# A unix system programming project on windows?

Tags: c, unix, posix, system

I was given a unix prgramming project (with of cours a use of signal handling and fork()) but i have some issues with my ubuntu and i prefer to work on windows. So is there a solution ? I installed Cygwin but i don't think it will be enough to compile and execute the files like in Linux.

Comment: Better you reinstall Ubuntu instead of trying and wasting your time to run it on windows !!

Comment: What "issues" do you have with Ubuntu, and why do you think Cygwin won't be enough?

Comment: The connection on my ubuntu disconects every 10 minutes when i am on my wifi so i have to reboot every 10 minutes. Whereas it is fine on windows. And the problem is that this disconection issue happens only on my wifi. So it is both because of my wifi, combined with the use of ubuntu. Which makes the problem hard to diagnose.

Comment: Do you really have to reboot to recover? I suggest you ask about the wifi problem on http://askubuntu.com/. BTW, if you want me to see a comment, flag me by including my name following an @ sign; click the "help" link next to the input window for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the project in Ubuntu.  You're going to have a hard enough time learning about signals and process handling without having to worry about various differences between Cygwin and actual unix/linux.

Another option is to install virtualbox and run Ubuntu within that.  There should be no differences there.  https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: +1 for VirtualBox (and VM in general). Works very well, including the corporate Windows-only monoculture.